# Control what files are copied to shared folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing

I have shared one folder on Windows 2008 server and would like to control what files are uploaded to it. I would like to let certain files to be uploaded, for example only *.doc files. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to look at using [File Server Resource Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734227%28WS.10%29.aspx) (FSRM) [File Screen](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734419%28WS.10%29.aspx).  With this you can restrict which file formats (by extension) are allowed on your server.  FSRM can also provide reporting, notification and alerts based on your rules.